# chrome extension eventpage onclicked not triggering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-listener

I'm aiming to fire an onclick event on a chrome extension using the documented onclicked eventlistener. It's not working.

## Below is the code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log(tab.url);
});
```

## Along with the manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Seneca One add Bookmark",
  "description": "Posts URL to database.",
  "version": "2.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "Favicon@2x.png",
    "default_title": "Add bookmark"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear, when do you want to trigger onclick event?

Comment: It is working. You need to look at the [correct console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/) as this is a separate hidden page.

Comment: Thankyou @wOxxOm !!